# How to use Elastic Search on top of a pre-existing SQL Database?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json, elasticsearch

I've been reading through a lot of good documentation about how to implement Elastic Search on a website with javascript or PHP.

Very good [introduction to ES](http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/basic-elasticsearch-concepts.html).

Very complete documentation [here](http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2013/07/01/elasticsearch-query-tutorial.html) and [here](http://exploringelasticsearch.com/modeling_data.html#sec-modeling-type-basics).

A whole [CRUD](http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/).

Elastic search with PHP: [here](https://speakerdeck.com/farrelley/elasticsearch-for-php-lone-star-php-2012), [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Elastica-PHP-client-for-elasticsearch-td1738187.html), and [here](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001907.html).

So the reason why I'm giving you those URLs is to understand how to use one or many of those great documentations when having a pre-existing SQL DB.

I'm missing the point somewhere: As they said Elasticsearch will create its own indexes and DB with MongoDB, I don't understand how can I use my (gigantic) database using SQL? Let say I have a MySQL DB, and I would like to use Elasticsearch to make my research faster and to propose the user pre-made queries, how do I do that? How does ES works over/along MySQL? How to transfer this gigantic set of Datas (over 8GB) into ES DB in order to be fully efficient at the beginning?

Many Thanks

Comment: Think of elasticsearch like another db, it's a document based NoSQL database (like MongoDB) opimized for search. You will have to index all the data into elasticsearch to use it.

Comment: So you mean I'll have to transfer every information I have in my actual DB into ES'NoSQL db ? Then every time I add something to my SQL DB, I have to make a copy to ES's DB?

Comment: There are techniques for keeping them in sync. Look up rivers. You only need to import information you might actually use for search, so might not be every field. Just think about how it would be able to search much faster than SQL without rearranging the data somehow? If it didn't need to be done then surely the mySQL database guys would have implemented something!

Comment: The way most people elasticsearch, is with a library, elastica for php, tire for ruby, etc... These usually have some way of making it easy to maintaing the elasticsearch indices based of your other datastore. Some people have used elasticsearch as their primary datastore, I'll leave you to read about that, but the impression I get is that it's not quite mature enough to do that.

Comment: Cool, I'm giving a look at https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica right now, you should write down an answer :)

Comment: What's the purpose of using Elastic Search as an indexer for your existing database when it already has an index of its own?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am using [jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) w/ mysql. It is very fast. You can configure them to continually poll data, or use one-time (one-shot strategy) imports.

e.g.

```
curl -xPUT http://es-server:9200/_river/my_river/_meta -d '
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "strategy" : "simple",
        "poll" : "5s",
        "scale" : 0,
        "autocommit" : false,
        "fetchsize" : 10,
        "max_rows" : 0,
        "max_retries" : 3,
        "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://mysql-server:3306/mydb",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "password*",
        "sql" : "select c.id, c.brandCode, c.companyCode from category c"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "mainIndex",
        "type" : "category",
        "bulk_size" : 30,
        "max_bulk_requests" : 100,
        "index_settings" : null,
        "type_mapping" : null,
        "versioning" : false,
        "acknowledge" : false
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need a more performant and scalable solution to the polling offered by jdbc-river, I recommend that you watch this presentation that explains how to perform incremental syncing from SQL Server into Elastic Search:

The principles discussed in the video also apply for other RDBMS -> NoSQL replication applications.

- [Adding Elasticsearch To An Existing .NET / SQL Server Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv-MflnT9qI) (You Tube)