# IndexMissingException[[wham] missing

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, elasticsearch, kibana

Browsing to: `http://127.0.0.1:9200/wham/_search`
Gives me:

```
{
  "error": "IndexMissingException[[wham] missing]",
  "status": 404
}
```

I've set everything up according to these documentations:

- http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/01/30/elasticsearch-indexing-sql-databases-the-easy-way/
- https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc
- https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Step-by-step-recipe-for-setting-up-the-river-with-PostgreSQL
- [How to use Elastic Search on top of a pre-existing SQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856457/how-to-use-elastic-search-on-top-of-a-pre-existing-sql-database)

The last one being the most helpful at the moment.
That sad, I've used two different "setup" queries via curl to create my river:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/wham/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "passywordu",
    "index": "source",
    "type": "wham",
    "sql": "select * from testtable;"
  }
}'
```

And then I've tried this which is a modified version of the last link above.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/wham/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "strategy": "simple",
    "poll": "5s",
    "scale": 0,
    "autocommit": false,
    "fetchsize": 10,
    "max_rows": 0,
    "max_retries": 3,
    "max_retries_wait": "10s",
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "passywordu",
    "sql": "select * from testtable",
    "index": "wham"
  }
}'
```

I'm currently using the last of the curls and `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/wham/_status` gives me this:

```
{
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "wham",
  "_id": "_status",
  "_version": 4,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "node": {
      "id": "v1DmcsEOSbKfEbjRdwLYOg",
      "name": "Miles Warren",
      "transport_address": "inet[/192.168.43.211:9300]"
    }
  }
}
```

So the river is there, I do however not see any queries arriving in my postgresql database engine. Which I've set up accordingly:

```
su - postgres
initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -E UTF8 -D '/tmp/testdb'
postgres -D /tmp/testdb
createdb testdb
psql -d testdb

CREATE TABLE testtable (
    source      varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    destination varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    service     int, NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES('192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.1', 80)
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES('192.168.0.11', '192.168.0.2', 21)
```

I can query the database on the default port, it runs fine with the username and password.
Where have I gone wrong? Have I misunderstood elasticsearch or shouldn't I be able to do `/wham/_search` and get all the results from mentioned SQL query?

Comment: you need to hit http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/wham/_search instead, _river is your index name, and wham is your type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confused with queries

**Query 1)**

```
  curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/wham/_meta' -d '{
        "type" : "jdbc",
        "jdbc" : {
            "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
            "user" : "postgres",
            "password" : "passywordu",
            "index" : "source",
            "type" : "wham",
            "sql" : "select * from testtable;"
        }
   }'
```

while using above query

you create an index named "**source**". With in that you create a index type of wham.
so after executing above **curl**. You need query for data using following format

```
    http://127.0.0.1:9200/source/wham/_search
```

it means search data inside index "source" and type "wham".

**Query 2)**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/wham/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
    "strategy" : "simple",
    "poll" : "5s",
    "scale" : 0,
    "autocommit" : false,
    "fetchsize" : 10,
    "max_rows" : 0,
    "max_retries" : 3,
    "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
    "url" : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb",
    "user" : "postgres",
    "password" : "passywordu",
    "sql" : "select * from testtable",
    "type": "typename", //add the type of documents to be indexed[like tables in RDBMS]
    "index" : "wham"
}
      }'
```

while using above query

you create an index named "**wham**". With in that you create a index type of wham.
so after executing above **curl**. You need query for data using following format

```
    http://127.0.0.1:9200/wham/typename/_search [or]   
    http://127.0.0.1:9200/wham/_search
```

it means search data inside index "wham" and indextype "typename".

before try above curl.delete the _river index and try.If the data is not important clear the data folder and try..!

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, took a while before i could get back into the environment and test the stuff out. I did confuse the format quite a bit. Your help got me quite far so for that I thank you even tho words can not describe the gratitude! ^^